# PHP countdown From day

Tags: php, mysql

i Put date in MySql database with this format: `2014-04-06` Now i need to print countdown from `NOW` until `2014-04-06`.

PHP Code :

```
$date = strtotime($row['end_date']);
$remaining = $date - time();
$days_remaining = floor($remaining / 86400);

echo $days_remaining;
```

Output :

```
1
```

This Output is False. True Output should be: 3 days .how do print this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I can think of suggesting, is making sure that you've set your timezone settings correctly. Something like,

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');

$now = time();
$your_date = strtotime('2014-04-06');
$datediff =  $your_date - $now;
$days_remaining = floor($datediff/(60*60*24));
echo $days_remaining; // echoes 2
```

I tried with this, and got 1 as the output:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/GMT-10');

$now = time();
$your_date = strtotime('2014-04-06');
$datediff =  $your_date - $now;
$days_remaining = floor($datediff/(60*60*24));
echo $days_remaining; // echoes 1
```

Comment: That's because it has been 8 hours since I posted that code, and hence the countdown is at 1 now.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way of finding the number of days between two dates.

```
<?php

     $now = time(); // or your date as well
     $your_date = strtotime($row['end_date']);
     $datediff =  $your_date - $now;
     $days_remaining = floor($datediff/(60*60*24));
     echo $days_remaining;

?>
```

Comment: `end_date` is bigger than `$now`.

Comment: Thanks, was a little typo.

Comment: Now, the question remains... how is this different from the code in the question?

Comment: there is no difference

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to execute the following sql statement and read its record by any mean you use in your app.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF('2014-04-06', CURDATE());
```